# Calculating the area of a circle using infinitesimal rectangles

Tags: calculus, integration

I wise to calculate the area of circle of radius $a$ using calculus and infinitesimal rectangles. Now I know integration and double and triple integrals but I am facing a peculiar problem and I am not able to tell where I am going wrong
[image]

Can someone point out where I am wrong and what is the right method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good method, even for a mathematician !

But your error comes from the fact that $AB d \theta$ is the hypothenuse of a small triangle, and you have to multiply it by $\sin \theta$ in order to recover the true width of your rectangle.

Therefore you will have to integrate

$$2a^2 \sin(\theta)^2$$

Check that you get $a^2 \pi$ in this way !

Comment: Thx understood !!

Answer (score 2):

To expand on @ArnaudMortier's answer, because $A$ has $x$-coordinate $a\cos\theta$, the rectangle's width is $-dx=-d(a\cos\theta)=a\sin\theta d\theta$, so the circle's area isn't $\int_0^\pi2a^2\sin^\color{red}{1}\theta d\theta$ but is rather $\int_0^\pi2a^2\sin^\color{limegreen}{2}\theta d\theta$, which is $\pi a^2$ as expected. (For example, we can write this integral as $a^2\int_0^\pi(1-\cos2\theta)d\theta$; the cosine averages to $0$, so makes no contribution.)

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is when you write $AB=a\operatorname{d}\!\theta$. $AB$ is smaller when $\theta$ is close to $0$ and larger when $\theta$ is close to $\frac \pi 2$, so you see that it should depend on $\theta$ and therefore $a\operatorname{d}\!\theta$ can't possibly be correct.

To find the correct formula you should draw a triangle with two of its sides equal to $AB$ and $\operatorname{d}\!\theta$.

However, I have to say that this method is the physicist way and should be avoided. The correct method is to use Riemann integration.